# Check if date field matches current month

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working on a SharePoint Online and I've a date field that I need to validate if the date insert by the user matches to the current month.

I have this formula:

```
=TEXT([Date],"mmmm")  ->This return the month
```

How do I compare this to the current month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MONTH function, it will return the month number. With this, there is also NOW() for the current date. Combining the two will get you the current month.

Now insert that in the column validation section. Return TRUE if it's ok, and false to show a message and block submit.

```
=IF(MONTH(NOW())<>MONTH(date),FALSE,TRUE)
```

On the logical side, don't forget to also check the YEAR if you want to be sure that it is the same month.

Comment: Minor note: NOW() returns a date+time , TODAY() returns a date